# How to block a range or list of phone numbers

Tags: iphone, spam

I get spam calls that begin with the same 6 digits as my own number. It's always a different number so I cant individually block them. Is there a way to block a whole list or a range of numbers?

The app Hiya tells me that these numbers are "spoofed" but does nothing to block them. I do not want my phone to ring. I do not care about false positives. I don't mind if a few legitimate calls get blocked along the way.

Comment: Would love to hear solutions for this. I have the same issue.