# My phone number has been “ghosted”. Is there anything I can do about that?

Tags: iphone

I’m now receiving phone calls from my own number. This ghosting of numbers has gotten completely out of hand! Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you are asking what I assume you are asking this should probably be addressed to your carrier.

Answer (score 1):

If your carrier won't block these, I suppose you could add your own number to a contact called "Telemarket Spam" and then block that caller.

There are apps that let you [make rules like "block all calls from the same 212-335-xxxx" area](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295720/how-to-block-a-range-or-list-of-phone-numbers) and then you would need to change your number to be in an area you're OK not ever getting a call from (if you're not already in that situation).

This is kind of like spam email - there's nothing from preventing anyone from sending mail as you - same as no one will police a phone scammer that sets your number as their "caller id". Unless the laws change in your area or your carrier decides to crack down, you have to block these or just not answer calls from anyone not in your address book by turning on "do not disturb".

To summarize, on iOS:

- use do not disturb and white list callers you don't mind ringing through
- use a third party [call screening app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190584/can-i-block-incoming-calls-using-wildcard-patterns) to set up rules and maintain a database of scammy numbers. These are all on the App Store and most are paid or they sell your number/call history to more scammers (or possibly both)
- use the blocking feature for specific black listed numbers

In your case, blocking your number seems the easiest fix for that specific malfeasance.